# ASCII grid creation

Tags: ocaml

I've created an OCaml function which generates an ASCII grid with a specified cell size and number of cells per row. A grid with a cell size of 2 (chars) and a number of 3 cells per row looks as following:

```
+--+--+--+
|  |  |  |
|  |  |  |
+--+--+--+
|  |  |  |
|  |  |  |
+--+--+--+
|  |  |  |
|  |  |  |
+--+--+--+
```

Here is the code:

```ml
let create_grid cell_size num_cells_on_row =
  let num_chars_per_col_row = ((cell_size + 1) * num_cells_on_row) + 1 in
  let rec create_row index margin filler res =
    if index = num_chars_per_col_row then res ^ "\n"
    else if index mod (cell_size + 1) = 0 then
      res ^ margin |> create_row (index + 1) margin filler
    else res ^ filler |> create_row (index + 1) margin filler
  in
  let rec create index res =
    if index = num_chars_per_col_row then res
    else if index mod (cell_size + 1) = 0 then
      create_row 0 "+" "-" res |> create (index + 1)
    else create_row 0 "|" " " res |> create (index + 1)
  in
  create 0 ""
;;

print_string (create_grid 2 3)
```

I'm looking on advice on how to make this code more idiomatic/functional, and maybe to find some standard library functions that I'm missing on and could have been helpful.